# Has a natural transformation between functors with codomain $Cat$ that is an equivalence on each component a weak inverse?

Tags: category-theory

Let $Cat$ be the category of small categories and $C$ another category. Suppose we have two functors $F,G\colon C\rightarrow Cat$ and a natural transformation $\eta\colon F\implies G$, that is an equivalence on each component, i.e. the functors $\eta_X\colon F(X)\rightarrow G(X)$ are equivalences of categories for each $X$.

Is there a natural transformation $\psi\colon G\implies F$, which is an equivalence in on each component? In other words, can I choose the "inverse" of $\eta_X$ coherently?

Comment: In general no, but you do get a _pseudonatural_ transformation.